# Saving All non-zero terms from a 2D array into another 1D array

Tags: c, arrays, function

`A` is a 2D array and I want to store all of its non zero terms in a new 1D array called `B`... this is a function that I call to do this, but it crashes the program, I don't know what am I doing wrong?

```
int doSomething(int A[N][N], int B[ ], int C[ ]){

    int i,j;
    int k=0;
    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        for(j=0; j<N; j++){
            if (A[i][j] != 0){
                B[k]= A[i][j];
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%d ", B[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you know that `i< 4` is the valid condition check? try `i< k` instead.

Comment: `B[]` must have `N*N` elements not `4`. So `int B[N*N]`.

Comment: `i < 4` should be `i < k`

Comment: It is clear that the function crashes: It has a bad name.

Comment: @DrKroch it could be an abbreviation for does hit

Comment: so N is already defined as 4 and B has space for 50 terms

Comment: I can't believe no one have said this yet: `int doSomething` is supposed to return an `int` and this function does not.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the `4` inside `for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)`. Probably the length of `B` array is less than 4 and therefore it causes error. Because you are accessing out of bound index. So you should use `for (i = 0; i < k; i++)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems.

First as @hamed said 'i' should be less than 'k' instead of less than '4'

Secondly you are assuming it is a square array which may not be the case (where the rows and columns are the same length)

```
int doSomething (int A[r][c], int B[ ]){

    int k=0;
    for(; r>0; r--){
        for(; c>0; c--){
            if (A[i][j] != 0){
                B[k]= A[i][j];
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = k-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%d ", B[i]);
    }
return B;
}
```

note: for more efficiency it is better to do the loops backwards in this case, you forgot to return B, and C (as far as I see) is unnessicsary

Comment: thanks but i forgot to mention A is a square matrix and it for this example it also happens to be a 4x4 matrix hence why i wrote I<4 in my code to try and simplify and figure out the problem....

Comment: k, are you sure it isn't because you did not return B

Comment: yeah i tried that too.. converted it to void even.. nothing